# Improving Speed of Histogram Back Projection

Tags: optimization, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I am currently using OpenCV's built-in patch-based histogram back projection (`cv::calcBackProjectPatch()`) to identify regions of a target material in an image. With an image resolution of 640 x 480 and a window size of 10 x 10, processing a single image requires ~1200 ms. While the results are great, this far too slow for a real-time application (which should have a processing time of no more than ~100 ms).

I have already tried reducing the window size and switching from `CV_COMP_CORREL` to `CV_COMP_INTERSECT` to speed up the processing, but have not seen any appreciable speed up. This may be explained by the OpenCV documentation (emphasis mine):

> Each new image is measured and then
>   converted into an image image array
>   over a chosen ROI. Histograms are
>   taken from this image image in an area
>   covered by a “patch” with an anchor at
>   center as shown in the picture below.
>   The histogram is normalized using the
>   parameter norm_factor so that it may
>   be compared with hist. The calculated
>   histogram is compared to the model
>   histogram; hist uses The function
>   cvCompareHist() with the comparison
>   method=`method`). The resulting
>   output is placed at the location
>   corresponding to the patch anchor in
>   the probability image dst. This
>   process is repeated as the patch is
>   slid over the ROI. **Iterative histogram
>   update by subtracting trailing pixels
>   covered by the patch and adding newly
>   covered pixels to the histogram can
>   save a lot of operations, though it is
>   not implemented yet.**

This leaves me with a few questions:

1. Is there another library that supports iterative histogram updates?
2. How significant of a speed-up should I expect from using an iterative update?
3. Are there any other techniques for speeding up this type of operation?

Comment: Number 1 way to speed up image processing: use smaller images.

Comment: Unfortunately, downsampling the images is not an option: I am already at the lower end of acceptable resolutions for the following processing stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in OpenCV Integral Histograms will definitely improve speed.

Please take a look at a sample implementation in the following link
http://smsoftdev-solutions.blogspot.com/2009/08/integral-histogram-for-fast-calculation.html